# Etiqueta <a> que redireccione a la página actual

Tags: html, html5

Necesito que una etiqueta  me direccione de nuevo a la misma página en la que estoy
¿Qué debo poner?¿currentpage o algo así?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

No estoy seguro de si deseas que una etiqueta X recargue la página y lo estás intentando con un `<a>` o si deseas que un `<a>` específicamente recargue la página.
Dejo varios ejemplos:

Sin nada en el `href` se recarga la página

```
<a href="">Recargar</a>
```

Con un **#** en el `href` se desliza al inicio de la pagina, es similar a un scroll-top.

```
<a href="#">Ir al top de la página</a>
```

Con un # + id ej: **#header** en el `href` se desliza hasta el elemento que tenga ese Id, se llama anclaje, ej:

```
<a href="#header">Posicionarse en etiqueta con Id header</a>
```

---

Por último es posible hacerlo por **JavaScript** de la siguiente manera en cualquier etiqueta.

**Opción 1:**

Primero definimos en **HTML** un `id` a la etiqueta que deseamos que al clickearla haga el `reload()`, ej:

```
<div id="recargar">Etiqueta para recargar Página</div>
```

Luego desde JavaScript hacemos se puede hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
//Capturamos la etiqueta
const etiquetaRecargar = document.getElementById("recargar")
//Escuchamos el evento **click** sobre esa etiqueta y lanzamos función al presionarla, en la función hacemos el reload()
etiquetaRecargar.addEventListener("click",()=>{location.reload()})
```

**Opción 2:**

Primero en **HTML** llamamos directamente a la función que hace el `reload()` en el onclick de la etiqueta, ej:

```
<div onclick="recargar()">Etiqueta para recargar Página</div>
```

Luego desde JavaScript hacemos se puede hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
//Ya no es necesario capturar la etiqueta, directamente escribimos la función que hace el reload()
const recargar = () => {
  location.reload();
};
```

Espero alguno de ellos te sirva para resolver, quedo a las ordenes.

Answer (score 0):

No tienes que hacer nada, solo deja vacío el `href=""` y cuando presiones la pagina se recargara.

Aunque no estoy seguro si funciona así en todos los navegadores, entonces puedes poner un evento click que recargue el sitio.
Algo tipo

```
function recargarPagina() {
 location.reload();
}
```

Y agregas el evento a tu boton

```
onclick="recargarPagina()"
```